# How can I get my SlickJS Carousal to cycle between 3 images and have them all visible while cycling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, slick.js

I am using SlickJS to build a slider that will allow me to cycle between images.

[Similar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ai4j.jpg)

[Link to SlickJS Documentation](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/README.markdown)

There area a couple of problems that I am running into.

The first is that, as far as I know, you cannot cycle between images if you are showing them all at once. For example if you set **slidesToShow** to 3 and you have only 3 images, you cannot cycle through them.

The other problem I have is that even when assigning custom buttons and running the **slickNext** and **slickPrev** functions through them, it still does not cycle.

Could anyone provide me guidance on how to get the slider to function similar to the image I provided above?

Here is the code I have:

```
 <div>
    <button class="left-selector" style="height: 20px; width: 20px">
    </button>
    <div class="center-ag-slider">
        <div>
            <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="https://keystonepuppies.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Siberian-Husky-Category-950x700.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="https://dgicdplf3pvka.cloudfront.net/2355971/siberian-husky-puppy-picture-473f7308-f278-4858-b1ec-81368845e1be.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzUzWDEwMjQ=/z/bCwAAOSwTM5YtzZy/%24_86.JPG">
        </div>

    </div>
    <button class="right-selector" style="height: 20px; width: 20px">
    </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.center-ag-slider').slick({
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '60px',
                slidesToShow: 3,
                initialSlide: 0,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 768,
                        settings: {
                            arrows: false,
                            centerMode: true,
                            centerPadding: '40px',
                            slidesToShow: 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            arrows: false,
                            centerMode: true,
                            centerPadding: '40px',
                            slidesToShow: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            $('.left-selector').click(function () {
                $(".center-ag-slider").slick("slickPrev");
            });
            $('.right-selector').click(function () {
                $(".center-ag-slider").slick("slickNext");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width on the `slick-slide` class in css that will display them all on the page simultaneously. So, in this case because there are 3 images you are trying to slide through you would set the width on `slick-slide` to be 33.333333%;

```
.slick-slide {
  width: 33.333333%;
}
```